# Process.Start leaves streams empty

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I have the code to run a console command/utility, monitor the live output using 'Debug.WriteLine' and write the final output to a log file when needed.

Edit: It does not work for Praatcon.exe an analysis command line utility. It can be downloaded [from here](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/download_win.html) . Just invoke praatcon.exe without argument, it should write on 'stdout' about the Usage. The code wont catch it.

The issue is, it works good for certain utilities and I can see the debug output as well as log in the file. But for certain utilities, I see empty commands, even though when I run those commands through a CMD window, I see the output. I am capturing both the streams Output and Error.

Can someone help me with this ?

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/fahadash/ConsoleSharp/blob/master/ConsoleSharp/CmdHelper.cs)

Here is how I am trying to do it

Initialization of ProcessStartInfo

```
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo(command, parameters)
        {
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
```

Running the process and initializing the string builders for output and error streams.

```
        var process = Process.Start(info);

        var output = new StringBuilder();
        var error = new StringBuilder();
```

Starting the tasks for Reading Streams

```
        var errorTask = process.StandardError.ReadLineAsync();

        var lineTask = process.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
```

Here is my while loop to monitor the progress and write output to the Debug Output window when there is any available.

```
            while (process.HasExited == false)
            {
                if (lineTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    output.AppendLine(lineTask.Result);

                    Debug.WriteLine(lineTask.Result);

                    lineTask = process.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
                }

                if (errorTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    error.AppendLine(errorTask.Result);

                    Debug.WriteLine(errorTask.Result);

                    errorTask = process.StandardError.ReadLineAsync();
                }

                errorTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0));
                lineTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0));
            }
```

After this, I am reading the streams further to see if there is anything left in there.

I get empty strings in output and error for one command. The only thing I get correct is the 'ExitCode'.

Please tell me if there is anything I am doing the wrong way.

Comment: Why are you using async?

Comment: The actual code is a bit more complicated. I shared the cleaner version. The actual code is getting heart-beat/pings that have to be responded.

Comment: @leppie ReadLineAsync isn't reliable ?

Comment: `ReadLineAsync` *is* reliable, but the way you are using it defeats the purpose of using `Async` methods. Accessing `.Result` will block the current thread until the task completes - that's what we are trying to avoid with `async/await`. If you want to use `ReadLineAsync` you should use `await errorTask;` rather than `errorTask.Result` and change your method to be an `async` method that returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on IRC, there was a possibility that the program you're calling may have been writing to a stream other than standard out or standard error. There are also streams with numbers 3-9 on Windows.

This was not the case with the process you were calling. It was actually using the Win32 call 'WriteConsole', which seems to access the console directly.

It would be possible to move the output back to stderr by preloading a DLL (DLL injection) but this is hackish, so as the source of the program is available, it's perhaps better to 'fix' it or submit a patch to the authors.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* doing the reading of the streams the wrong way, in the sense that you should not be polling. I don't see any specific reason that would cause the behavior you've (vaguely) described. But just in case, I offer this correct implementation of the reading:

```
async Task ConsumeStream(StreamReader reader, StringBuilder builder)
{
    string line;

    while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(line);
        Debug.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Then call that method like this:

```
var errorTask = ConsumeStream(process.StandardError, error);
var lineTask = ConsumeStream(process.StandardOutput, output);

// Technically superfluous, since you'll also wait on the tasks,
// but won't hurt.
process.WaitForExit();

Task.WaitAll(errorTask, lineTask);

// error and output StringBuilders will be valid here
```

Comment: Your code does not work either. I have updated the question. It is just one exe whose output is not captured. Please see my question again. Sorry about the example part.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood the point of an MCVE as described in the link I provided. Anyway, it seems that you have a specific program that is simply not writing to the streams you are reading, so the code above won't fix that. But it _will_ at least fix your misuse of the `async` mechanism, so you should still use this example even if it's not actually an answer to the specific question.